# Directory navigation issue

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory

files : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAQLy.png

So I have an html file called hello.html and a folder called hello. But if you go to website.com/hello it will come come up with a 404 error because it finds the folder and not the html file. I have a .htaccess file that looks like this..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But I am not sure what I can do to fix this. I want website/hello to go to hello.html and not the hello folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could have an index.html page redirecting the user to the hello.html page when a user goes to the hello directory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. I have an href on the index that links to hello. <a href="hello">. and if I link to hello.html then the .html part shows up in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/hello/ http://www.example.com/hello.html
```

Comment: I tried putting that below the other lines in my .htaccess file and didn't work.